# ARP discovery on multiple subnets

Tags: switch, local-area-network, subnet, arp

I have an unmanaged switch which serves traffic belonging to different subnets. Lets say these are the subnets:

```
192.168.0.0/24
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/24
And few more subnets which I am not aware of.
```

I have a Linux machine having `192.168.0.1` as IP on `192.168.0.0/24` subnet. Using this machine I want to discover the arp address's of all the machines that are on different subnets. After arp address's are found, I want to discover their IP address's too. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ettercap.
You may want to google for "arp spoofing" and "switched sniffing" for more details.